# How to count total number of results return by list and display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am using MVC 4.
I binding result in grid based on my search criteria in web grid. and i am showing 10 records per page.
the question is.
How can i show the total count of records below the grid.
i tried counting the result list in control and show it in view.
if i use

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberOfRows)
```

it returns result in the text box
but if i use label means if shows property name instead of total count.

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberOfRows)
```

Why label show property name. How can i show the total count. or is it possible to show the total count in web grid itself?
please help.

Comment: _Why label show property name?_ Because that what `LabelFor()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelFor()` in MVC is used to display model property names,so instead using `LabelFor()`,if you are binding value to `NumberOfRows` from controller action then

Instead of

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberOfRows)
```

Try

```
@Model.NumberOfRows
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to show the total count in webgrid itself.

Comment: or may be ``DisplayFor()``